# Issue with row level trigger

Tags: plsql

Can someone please let me know what mistake am I doing in the below code
Why is it giving below compilation error?

```
create or replace trigger emp_trigger
before insert or update or delete on emp
for each row
begin
 if inserting then
  dbms_output.put_line('Before inserting Old value is '|| :old.salary ||' New value : '|| :new.salary);
 elsif updating then
  dbms_output.put_line('Before updating Old value is '|| :old.salary ||' New value : '|| :new.salary);
 elsif deleting then
  dbms_output.put_line('Before deleting Old value is '|| :old.salary ||' New value : '|| :new.salary);
 end if;
end;
/


Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

SQL> show err;
Errors for TRIGGER EMP_TRIGGER:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
3/59     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.SALARY'
3/91     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.SALARY'
5/58     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.SALARY'
5/90     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.SALARY'
7/58     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.SALARY'
7/90     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.SALARY'
```

Comment: does the emp table have a `salary` column?

Comment: Sorry, the emp table have sal column

Answer (score 1):

Works fine now

```
create or replace trigger emp_trigger
before insert or update or delete on emp
for each row
begin
 if inserting then
  dbms_output.put_line('Before inserting Old value is '|| :old.sal ||'
                 New value : '|| :new.sal);
 elsif updating then
  dbms_output.put_line('Before updating Old value is '|| :old.sal ||'
                 New value : '|| :new.sal);
 elsif deleting then
  dbms_output.put_line('Before deleting Old value is '|| :old.sal ||'
                 New value : '|| :new.sal);
 end if;
end;
/
```